# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: camera is not defined

Tags: javascript, codenameone

I have JS camera object in codenameone project while I am trying to call that object from a js file its giving me the Uncaught ReferenceError: camera is not defined
error in my chrome browser, while i am trying to upload a image

Below is my codenameone code

```
camera.set("capture",new JSFunction(){
public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
Display.getInstance().openImageGallery(new ActionListener(){
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
String imagePath ="";
if(evt!=null){
imagePath=(String)evt.getSource();
final JSObject uploadedFile = (JSObject)ctx.get("document.getElementById('uploadedFile')");
uploadedFile.set("value",imagePath);
}
}
});
}
});
ctx.set("camera", camera);
```

Below is my js file where i am getting error for the camera object I used to give window.camera but at that its giving the same above error for capture where capture is the button id which i am using in my html file.

Below is my js file

```
 document.getElementById('capture')
.addEventListener('click', function(){
camera.capture(function(){
var results = document.getElementById("uploadedFile").value;
document.getElementById("uploadedFile").value=results;
})
}, true);
```

Comment: So you're using the CN1 javascript bridge, but you say you're using the Chrome browser?  The javascript bridge is designed for use with the Cn1 BrowserComponent.  If you're running a page outside the context of a Cn1 app, the bridge isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

JS camera file is not loaded thats why you are getting this error.

Make sure file is loaded above this code.

structure should be like this-->

**file src included**
then-->
**your script here**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to access HTML5 API's within an embedded browser component. It doesn't have access to all the bells and whistles of HTML5 and might fail. I'm not sure if these will work on the device either although you would have a better chance there than in the simulator.

Comment: in simulator i am able to browse my file and getting that filepath in my html file through javascript but in my html file i am using formData to submit that form its having an ajax call to send the data on input type submit but on submit its not able to submit  the form.As input type file works only on browser and won't work for mobile app so I am using CN1 javascript bridge using codenameone files. So, how to submit the form data on ajax call.

Comment: Just do this from Java using the `MultipartRequest` class. Check out its JavaDoc for usage sample